# SSH from my local machine to linux host and sudo to root user

Tags: python, linux, ssh, sudo, tty

Used subprocess to ssh to host.

Here is the code snippet i used to ssh and run commands as my user. When i try to use sudo command i get error related to tty -- not a terminal (something like that)

```
 sshProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', hostname], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=0)
sshProcess.stdin.write("hostname\n")
sshProcess.stdin.write("ls -ldr %s \n"%path)
sshProcess.stdin.write("pwd \n")
sshProcess.stdin.close()
for line in sshProcess.stdout:
 if line == "END\n":
 break
 print(line,end="")
```

But i am not able to run below command

```
sshProcess.stdin.write("sudo su - serviceuser \n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force a pseudo-tty allocation by specifying **-t** option.

```
subprocess.Popen(['ssh -t', hostname], .....
```

From `man ssh`

> ```
>  -t
> ```
>
> Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t optionsforce tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

Comment: I tried it previously, but did not work

I am getting below error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssh.py", line 11, in <module>
    sshProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ssh -t', hostname], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I added shell=True in Popen but i am getting someother error

sshProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ssh -t', hostname], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=0)

Comment: usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]

Comment: @Springhills You should [edit] your question to add this new information there.